# Is it possible to re-order view values by using map reduce?

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase, couchbase-view, go-couchbase

I need to reorder the coiuchbase views results based on the values.I am writing a map reduce like below and did sorting using group, reduce and descending keys.

```
function (doc, meta) {
 if(doc.transactionType=='Transaction') 
  {
    for(var i=0; i<doc.transactionList.length; i++)  
     {  
         if(doc.transactionList[i].bucket==1)  { 
          emit(doc.transactionList[i].transactionId,null);
         }
     } 
  } 
}
```

Reduce= _count
I got the result the way i was expecting. I know couchbase views filter on the basis of keys only.

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":"Transaction1","value":2},
  {"key":"Transaction3","value":3},
  {"key":"Transaction4","value":1}
  ] 
}
```

Is it possible to get the below results. If so, any advice what I am missing here?

```
{"rows":[
    {"key":"Transaction3","value":3},
    {"key":"Transaction1","value":2},
    {"key":"Transaction4","value":1}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not sort by value in couchbase. Only by key
You should sort before inserting or after requesting data from view

Comment: I agree, but is there any optimized workaround for it because my priority is to not sort by the transactionsId infact by value. But I can't revert because I have to use groupby on the basis of transactionId.

Comment: why you can't group your documents by Id, not value? Sort by id and group by value

Comment: Here, value is the count after the groupby of the key document Id. So, I can't group by value. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Create another view, than will order by key. Call you current view, get documents with count, and call second view, where count will be key. Not elegant but i think it's will work...